# Legal Ethics: Government lawyers giving legal advice & ABA rule 4.3?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, professional-ethics

I submitted a request for information to a government agency and got back an answer from a lawyer that seems to constitute legal advice prohibited under DC bar rule 4.3.  **Would a government (law enforcement) general counsel have some exemption from the rule dealing with unrepresented persons?**

In a surprisingly brief reply, the attorney said only:

> The United States Capitol Police respectfully declines to provide the information requested in your July 26, 2021 email below. The information and communications requested are not public records subject to the public right of access under federal common law.
> <end of message>

Shouldn't that be considered **legal advice**?   I would think advising his client would be fine, but not a public member, particularly as his opinion puts my interests in conflict with the organizations.

Background: In a single e-mail, I requested six specific categories of records from the Capitol Police.   Furthermore, I requested them under the common law Right to Public Records because the same lawyer has (in response to other requestors) refused the request on the basis that FOIA does not apply.

The guy didn't even identify his role in the organization. As he didn't, I checked him out on LinkedIn, where he describes himself as Senior Counsel & *Ethics Attorney* for the Capitol Police.

I'm not asking if he's right, but if his response brings his own ethics into question?

**Legal Advice vs legal information**

> Unlike legal information, legal advice refers to the written or oral counsel about a legal matter that would affect the rights and responsibilities of the person receiving the advice. In addition, actual legal advice requires careful analysis of the law as it applies to a person's specific situation - as opposed to speculation based on generic facts.  -- https://www.findlaw.com/hirealawyer/do-you-need-a-lawyer/what-is-legal-advice.html

Comment: Suppose I owe you some money. You come to me and say "give me my money!". I reply "nah, I do not legally owe you anything". What would that be you think, legal advice?

Comment: I suspect most people are downvoting because they think the answer is obvious. The guy isn't giving you any advice; he's just telling you why he's not complying with your request. It's an entirely routine communication, and I doubt any disciplinary authority in the country would find it objectionable in any way.

Comment: @bdb484 So the community discourages questions that some members feel have obvious answers?  That doesn't jibe with the prohibition on my deleting the question, answers like David's can be valuable to others with questions similar to mine.   It distinguishes between legal advice and taking a position, rather than just saying that's obvious...

Comment: I can't speak for "the community." I can say that most users on Law.SE know very little about the law, and that their inexperience often results in them voting down questions or answers because they don't appreciate how uncertain modern legal systems make everything. There just aren't very many people providing useful information here, whether that means answers or up/downvotes. I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: @bdb484: I won't take it personally, thanks.   I wouldn't even mind the downvote if they put in a comment with constructive criticism or describing their reason.   But there's not much point in getting worked up over it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not legal advice, It is not even primarily a legal opinion. It is a **legal position**. The lawyer, acting on behalf of the agency from which you requested information, is giving the reasons why that agency is declining your request. The lawyer is presumably either an employee of the agency, or has the agency as a client. In any case, this is notice of the position that the agency would be likely to adopt if you took further legal action, such as a suit to compel disclosure.

Lawyers provide such position statements ion behalf of clients or employers all the time. Such statements indicate why certain action is taken, what basis the client or employer has for taking or not taking certain action, and often indicate the nature of the defenses or theories that will be used should a lawsuit follow, although the client or employer is free to change the theory at the pleading stage.

Not only is it not unethical for the lawyer to respond in this way, the agency is, I am fairly sure, **required** by the law to provide a valid reason when a request is declined. That is what they have done, provide a reason that they claim is valid, with some legal reasoning about why it is valid.

Note that I express no view on whether the reason given is in fact valid, or would be sustained in a suit. That would be a different question.

Comment: Thanks again David, sounds like a reasonable distinction to me, and I understood it to be a position (stated as a fact).   So I asked in reply for even a single precedent supporting his position.   Would he be ethically able to answer that?   Does he have an obligation to show such legal reasoning?.

Comment: @Burt_Harris I don't see any ethical reason why the lawyer should not answer. It is clear that s/he is not advising you, your interests are if anything opposed to those of his or her  client/employer. I doubt that s/he is **required** to respond, unless you actually file suit. But there are several reasons why s/he might choose to. I suggest being as polite as possible, and trying not to sound like an obsessed nut, I am sure they see a lot of those.

Comment: Thanks, yes.  I simply asked him to check his position against a definition of federal common law public records from a 1996 appeal.   I'll provide the cite if you are interested.  I certainly don't want to get litigious if further civil communications can address the issue.

Answer (score 3):

### Legal advice? It isn't even advice.

What has this person suggested that you do? Have they advised you of what your legal rights and remedies are? Have they suggested you lose weight or stop smoking?

**There is no advice here of any sort.**

Comment: The attorney looked at the specifics of information I requested rendered an opinion about the applicability of common law to the request I made.   I think that fits the definition of legal advice.

Comment: @Burt_Harris You might think that, but it doesn't. At all.

Comment: Are you guys lawers?

Comment: @Burt_Harris It shouldn't really make any difference to you whether the guys are lawyers. Because even if they are, they are not _your_ lawyers.

Comment: I think knowing they were lawyers should make a difference, as it suggests they might know what they're talking about. As it stands, neither the answer nor the comment cites any sources, mentions any law, applies any legal reasoning, or bears any other indicia of legal reasoning. Without anything to distinguish the answer from an uninformed rant, I think it makes sense to ask if it comes from someone whose credentials suggest they should be taken seriously.

Comment: If they were lawyers, wouldn’t that constitute legal advice? Just asking

Comment: @bdb484 where is "The information and communications requested are not public records subject to the public right of access under federal common law." an advice? It is "My client believes this, therefor we deny"

Comment: Not in the relevant jurisdiction, certainly.

Comment: @kisspuska lawyers can to talk to people without it being legal advice

Comment: @DaleM I agree! I tried to point at the absurdity of the OP of an implied accusation of being given legal advice, and wrong for that matter, than seeks answers online from users who we frankly, can't even know for fact if they are not bots let alone lawyers, and then having a problem when not receiving the answer sought.